# Override condition expression using automation script in Maximo

Tags: python, maximo

I would like to know whether there is a way to override an condition expression using automation script ? For example a restriction has been put in place for some status however this status should get changed through script which is getting invoked via workflow. Below is the example , we have a condition set on WAPPR so that it doesn't come in change status dialog however it should allow user to change the status using WF. This script is getting called however we get error as the status is not present in the value list.

```
mbo.changeStatus('WAPPR',MXServer.getMXServer().getDate(),'autoscript',MboConstants.NOACCESSCHECK | MboConstants.NOVALIDATION_AND_NOACTION)
```

Comment: Could you provide some example code and the expected output?

Comment: @API added the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the status value to the status value list?

Answer (score 0):

Add a non-persistent attribute to the object, set it with your workflow and check that attribute's value in the conditional expression. Then your code should work.